# SQL injection on clean url

Tags: seo, sqlmap

I would like to test my website for SQL injection using sqlmap. I'm using mod_rewrite and my URL looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/forum/&nav_page=1
```

(where nav_page is the parameter name and 1 is value)

The problem I'm having is that I can't find a way to tell sqlmap to perform the injection test just on the value.

The URL also not contain the `?` sign because it's SEO friendly.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand I am using: ./sqlmap.py -u "http://www.example.com/forum/&nav_page=1" --dbs --randomg-agent -o and it check the entire url I want to check just the value position(1)

Comment: Just because your 'clean url' doesn't contain a `?` doesn't mean your servlet won't read `url parameters`.

Comment: Try `*` to mark the injection point.

Comment: Basically speaking; if you take the values from an url and plug it directly into the database - you're vulnerable; regardless of whether you want a seo friendly url (? is seo friendly too, and still used by the way)

Answer (score 1):

Your ideas of seo-frienliness are quite vague. It is not symbols that make an url look "seo-friendly". It's technology that doesn't  involve parameter names and values.

So, you have to decide either you are using query string parameters or not. 
If not - make your urls real seo-friendly. like http://www.example.com/forum/nav_page1/
If you still want to use query string variables - then use them properly, using ? mark to define a query string.